# Discord.py Custom Status

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a status command which shows the person who uses the command or the person mentioned in the command's username, nickname, ID, account creation date, join server date and status. However when I try using `member.status` it doesn't show the custom status of the person. Is there any way that I can make the bot show the custom status?

Comment: enable intents.presences

Comment: I have all enabled.

Comment: In discord.py everybody can't create custom status. This is a problem for all of bots

Comment: I am not saying that I want to create sutom status I am saying that i want to see people's custom status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check `member.activites` This will get (custom + game) or one of them. You have to check which is the custom.

- [Member.activities](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20activities#discord.Member.activities)
- [discord.CustomActivity](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20activities#discord.CustomActivity)

```py
all_status = member.activities
for status in all_status:

    if isinstance(status, discord.CustomActivity):
        print(status.name)
```